# Pretty way to instantiate a class from a dict value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, instantiation

Let's say I have this:

```
a = {1: __class}
```

Is there any alternative to this ugly piece `a[1]()` ?

Also, tried `a[1].__call__(argument)` but PyCharm complains about `Expected type 'type', got X instead`

It seems to me that it defeats this statement:

> Explicit is better than implicit

I am not asking what is the correct form of doing it. I use this form, and I know is right. I only asked for any alternatives.

Comment: Whats ugly about it?

Comment: What you're doing is the right way.

Comment: I actually think this looks more intuitive.

Comment: Get over it, it's normal when dealing with first-order functions.

Comment: Read about The zen of Python -> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3

Comment: You could also use `type(a[1]).__call__(a[1])` if you find it more readable, but I'm not sure it actually is.

Comment: You are being explicit... If you knew python as a language that syntax is fine. Otherwise I would recommend the answer below.

Comment: Using `__call__` and other `__dunder__` methods directly is generally a bad practice, outside of a few specific circumstances. There's nothing wrong with `a[1]()` at all. It makes total sense and it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing wrong with `a[1]()`, if you really want to argue that it's not explicit enough...

```
the_callable_object_that_i_pulled_from_the_dictionary= a[1]
the_callable_object_that_i_pulled_from_the_dictionary()
```

Comment: I guess that name should be `the_callable_object_that_i_pulled_from_the_dictionary`.

Comment: Oh my! You're totally right! The name was not explicit enough to make sure the reader knew that the object would have been callable. Thanks for the great catch.